# How can i get Request and Response data Result

Tags: jmeter

Hi Iam Fresher in Jmeter

I have wrote one Java Sampler code(Copy& Paste) ,after running this code getting success message but Request and Response data are not displaying..How can i get Request and Response data and I want to pass some parameter also,is it possible

My Jsampler code is

```
package com.wordpress.newspaint.jmeter.java.demo;

import java.io.Serializable;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.AbstractJavaSamplerClient;
import org.apache.jmeter.config.Arguments;
import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JavaSamplerContext;

public class ExampleJavaTestClassRR extends AbstractJavaSamplerClient implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // set up default arguments for the JMeter GUI
    @Override
    public Arguments getDefaultParameters() {
        Arguments defaultParameters = new Arguments();
        defaultParameters.addArgument("URL", "http://www.google.com/");
        defaultParameters.addArgument("SEARCHFOR", "newspaint");
      //  defaultParameters.addArgument("ENTITY","BANK");
        return defaultParameters;
    }

    public SampleResult runTest(JavaSamplerContext context) {       
        String urlString = context.getParameter( "URL" );
        String searchFor = context.getParameter( "SEARCHFOR" );
      //  String ENTITY = context.getParameter( "ENTITY" );

        SampleResult result = new SampleResult();
        result.sampleStart(); // start stopwatch

        try {
            java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL(urlString + "?q=" + searchFor);
            java.net.HttpURLConnection connection = (java.net.HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection(); // have to cast connection
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.connect();
            result.setSuccessful( true );
            result.setResponseMessage("URL IS"+ url);
            result.setResponseMessage( "Successfully performed actionSSSSn" );
            result.setResponseCodeOK(); // 200 code
        } catch (Exception e) {
           // result.sampleEnd(); // stop stopwatch
            result.setSuccessful( false );
            result.setResponseMessage( "Exception: " + e );

            // get stack trace as a String to return as document data
            java.io.StringWriter stringWriter = new java.io.StringWriter();
            e.printStackTrace( new java.io.PrintWriter( stringWriter ) );
            result.setResponseData( stringWriter.toString() );
            result.setDataType( org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult.TEXT );
            result.setResponseCode( "500" );
        }
        result.sampleEnd();
        return result;
    }
    void teardownTest() {
        System.out.println("inside tear Down:");
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to use some of these methods: http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#getResponseMessage%28%29 ?

Answer (score 4):

**First**:

Your code sample isn't very correct.

This line:

```
result.setResponseData( stringWriter.toString() );
```

According to JavaDoc, it's deprecated

```
/**
 * Sets the responseData attribute of the SampleResult object.
 * Should only be called after setting the dataEncoding (if necessary)
 *
 * @param response
 *            the new responseData value (String)
 *
 * @deprecated - only intended for use from BeanShell code
 */
```

So if you want to set response data this way you need to use i.e. [__Beanshell](http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-using-functions) function

The correct way of invocation of setResponseData is either

```
result.setDataEncoding("UTF-8");
result.setResponseData("Everything is fine".getBytes());
```

or

```
result.setResponseData("Everything is fine", "UTF-8);
```

**Second:**

Your code assumes result return only in failure case. Change default http://www.google.com/ URL to some URL which does not exist and you'll get exception stacktrace as a response.

If you need something to be returned on success as well you need to add any of lines above at the end of your try block.

**Third:**

As far as I'm aware you are not able to set request data for Java Request. You need to develop a sampler to be able to set it. I recommend to look into sources for ExampleSampler

```
/src/examples/org/apache/jmeter/examples/sampler/ExampleSampler.java
```

and for existing JavaTest and SleepTest Java Request samplers:

```
/src/protocol/java/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/java/test/JavaTest.java
/src/protocol/java/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/java/test/SleepTest.java
```

All three contain answer to "I want to pass some parameter also,is it possible" piece

Sources are available from [JMeter download page](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi)

Comment: Thank u Dmitri..Iam trying this way

Comment: Thank u Dmitri..Iam trying this way and I need anthor hepl also..how to write setupTest,Can u give me the sample setupTest for above code