# JavaSampler Result

Tags: jmeter

Hi Iam Fresher in `Jmeter`

I have wrote one Java Sampler code. I don't know that is correct or wrong. If I put that URL and parameter in `Http Request` getting proper result, but if written as a `javasampler` i didn't get that result, Iam getting Pass result but no response and request data

My Sampler code is:

```
package org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.test;

import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.io.StringWriter;

import org.apache.jmeter.config.Arguments;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.AbstractJavaSamplerClient;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JavaSamplerContext;
import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult;



public class ExampleJavaSampler extends AbstractJavaSamplerClient implements Serializable {
    String mySvc = "";
    JavaSamplerContext context; 
    public Arguments getDefaultParameters(){
        Arguments arg = new Arguments();
        arg.addArgument("url", "http://www.url.com:5252/Switch/Download");
        arg.addArgument("e_type", "bank");
        arg.addArgument("e_id", "4");
        arg.addArgument("b_id", "1");
        arg.addArgument("a_id", "0002");
        arg.addArgument("link_branch", "");
        arg.addArgument("terminal_id", "");
        arg.addArgument("version", "10");
        arg.addArgument("entity", "100");
        System.out.println("inside default");
        return arg;     
    }

    public void setupTest(JavaSamplerContext context) {

        System.out.println("inside Setup");

    }


    public SampleResult runTest(JavaSamplerContext context) {

        System.out.println("Inside Run test:");
        String urls = context.getParameter("url");
        String e_type = context.getParameter("e_type");
        String e_id = context.getParameter("e_id");
        String b_id = context.getParameter("b_id");
        String a_id = context.getParameter("a_id");
        String l_branch = context.getParameter("e_type");
        String t_id = context.getParameter("e_type");
        String oion = context.getParameter("e_type");
        String entity = context.getParameter("e");



        SampleResult result = new SampleResult();
        result.getURL();
        result.setSampleLabel("Test Result");
        result.setDataType(SampleResult.TEXT);
        result.sampleStart();
        try{
         java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL(urls+"?=e_type="+e_type+"&e_id="+e_id+"&b_id="+b_id);
         System.out.println(url);
         java.net.HttpURLConnection connection = (java.net.HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection(); // have to cast connection
         connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
         connection.connect();

         result.sampleEnd(); // stop stopwatch
         result.setSuccessful( true );
         result.setResponseMessage( "Successfully performed action" );
         result.setResponseCodeOK(); // 200 code
     } catch (Exception e) {
         result.sampleEnd(); // stop stopwatch
         result.setSuccessful( false );
         result.setResponseMessage( "Exception: " + e );

         // get stack trace as a String to return as document data
         java.io.StringWriter stringWriter = new java.io.StringWriter();
         e.printStackTrace( new java.io.PrintWriter( stringWriter ) );
         result.setResponseData( stringWriter.toString() );
         result.setDataType( org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult.TEXT );
         result.setResponseCode( "500" );
     }

        return result;
    }
    void teardownTest() {
        System.out.println("inside tear Down:");
    }

}
```

After this code I made `.jar` file and put  `lib/ext`. Then I called in Javarequest and all parameters are  diplayed there, then I run this Test plan, getting success message nut no result

This is the right way or we have to add some thing for there for result?

Answer (score 1):

I've already responded [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19857440/how-can-i-get-request-and-response-data-result/).

You need to call result.setResponseData() **inside** your *try* block elsewise you won't see anything on success. "Response Data" piece of "View Results Tree" listener is populated only on error according to your code.